# PayPal live payments not authorized

Tags: paypal

I am having problems getting PayPal to accept live payments from my app. I am using an Azure server, coding in C#, with a Xamarin-based Android client app. I can get everything working with the PayPal sandbox, but it fails when I switch to live credentials.
Here is my payment flow:

1) In my Android app, start the PayPal app to authorize a payment. This returns an authorization code. This code is something like C21AAHHVxYjktRk82SomDGL6ssqd85LLmso5uxADtMW4ABEyieWdC_6mUxWK84hfeteotgeorgiengeoiugHUWRiu-Q

2) Pass the code up to the server; use the code, with a grant_type of client_credentials, to get a bearer token. The returned token is something like this :

```
"scope": "https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/futurepayments openid https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*",
"nonce": "2017-12-31T12:07:46ZPYBveV0qcOc2apceqHbTBrXXVsuGCryP05-xxxxxxxxxxx",
"access_token": "A23AAHweO7uu8vuXs45CVOafwqFHGj03riRShISJRnHn4Pr1bzwdDfaG5JkqCT5oZ_pFWGBK-wScOq2JeDERe2USxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 28800,
"refresh_token": "R23AAFR7MtimwU1AeQ7V6pTw0ugxN4AzOsRr-tBfmChMBAK8IMrJO_WQ6WgLUxbkK8ssvHoPVFFdVVAorNZriMX8gUA1tb-iRzwj7aiQ3_KCv5SDnqjf5j3vxKeZG052Q7WpSbW2zxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

3) Submit a REST request along with the bearer token to authorize the payment. The REST request would be like this :

```
{
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "currency": "GBP",
            "total": 1.0
        },
        "payee": {
            "email": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "description": "Test item",
        "payment_options": {
            "allowed_payment_method": "INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE"
        }
    }
```

Please note that we have to set the payee in our request as we are not receiving the payments ourselves.

The response I get back is like this :

```
"id":"PAY-258208691145776xxxxxxxxx",
    "intent":"sale",
    "state":"created",
    "cart":"1JF69642C9xxxxxxx",
    "transactions":[
        {
            "amount":{
                "total":"1.00",
                "currency":"GBP"
            },
            "payee":{
                "merchant_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "email":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "description":"Test item",
            "related_resources":[]
        }
    ],
    "redirect_urls":{
        "return_url":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/return?paymentId=PAY-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "cancel_url":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/cancel"
    },
    "create_time":"2018-08-20T10:22:19Z",
    "update_time":"2018-08-20T10:22:20Z",
    "links":
    [
        {
            "href":"https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "rel":"self","
            "method":"GET"
        },
        {
            "href":"https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/execute",
            "rel":"execute",
            "method":"POST"
        },
        {
            "href":"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "rel":"approval_url","method":"REDIRECT"
        }
    ]
```

All good so far.

4) Execute the payment and return the response to the client app. 
This is the request to execute the payment, I am using the access_token from step (1) and the payment URL of https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/execute :

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    try
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("en-GB"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(paymentURL);
        ret1 = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

This all works fine on PayPal's sandbox. When I try to run it live, it fails at the final step with a MALFORMED_REQUEST error.

So I ran a test transaction using cURL (i.e. entirely manually, copying and pasting the commands in), using the same payment details. The payment flow was slightly different, but it worked. However, I got a client_id back from PayPal which is not present in the response I get from step (3), so I am unable to run my actual transaction using cURL, but I suspect this is because the cURL approach is a web payment flow (i.e. I end up on PayPal's website to authorize the payment) whereas my system does not use the web, only PayPal's mobile app. Incidentally, the long code returned by that app does not work in a cURL request.

Something seems very wrong here, but it works in the sandbox, even if I use a grant_type of authorization_code in step 1 (but live, that grant_type fails in step 2). I am using the correct live PayPal id and secret.
Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong here? I have tried PayPal support but they only suggested to use cURL which I cannot do without a client_id for the transaction.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally had an answer from PayPal, and apparently they have to approve your account before they will enable future payments, which is what I was originally using to get a grant type of authorization_code which should then allow me to set the payee in the REST response. What I was doing in the steps outlined above was just following the instructions from PayPal's technical support, which didn't work anyway. Hopefully this will resolve the problem, but it would have been really helpful if PayPal had put this information somewhere on the developer site (perhaps it is buried in there somewhere, but I haven't found it yet).

Comment: from where do we need to get approval? is there any option on dashboard?

Comment: It's been a few years since I was involved with this, but I had to contact PayPal support directly and they said that PayPal would not approve non-US accounts for future payments (I am in the UK), so that was that. I don't know if this is still the case.